# Google healthcare: No logro conectarme desde el exterior del cluster

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

Tengo un problema al intentar conectarme a la api de Google Healthcare.
Cree todo como indica la guía
Y al intentar subir una imagen DICOM con el comando dmsend de la biblioteca DCMTK me arroja este error de conexión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Link de la guía: https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/dicom-connect-pacs

Comment: A dónde estás apuntando la petición? Ese mensaje de error básicamente dice que no pudo conectarse con lo que esperaba que estuviese escuchando del otro lado. Revisa tu firewall (haz una prueba apagándolo, a ver si tienes que establecer una nueva regla de conexiones salientes), revisa que sí haya un servicio disponible en la URL a la que intentas conectarte

Comment: apunta  a la direccion que me dio el LoadBalancer Ingress

Comment: Con el firewall apagado pasa lo mismo